# What is key when exporting signed app?

Tags: android, intellij-idea

When I use IntelliJ IDEA to export signed Android app, I have option to generate one private keystore and many keys within it.

What is the function of these keys? Should I generate a new key for each app update and name it accordingly?

At the moment I am generating one keystore for each app.

---

Another question: When creating a new key, is the info from the image optional or obligatory?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1- What is the function of these keys?

The Android system will not install or run an application that is not signed appropriately. This applies wherever the Android system is run, whether on an actual device or on the emulator. For this reason, you must set up signing for your application before you will be able to run or debug it on an emulator or device.

> 2- Should I generate a new key for
>   each app update and name it
>   accordingly?

no need to generate new key for each app. Yo can use the existing key that you have previously generated.

> 3- When creating a new key, is the
>   info from the image optional or
>   obligatory?

Yes this is optional. You have provide this information.

for more information..http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html

Comment: Oh, so the "key" is the actual sign key, while "keystore" is just a container for keys. Right?

Comment: Does is mean that I need to create just one keystore named by my company's name? all the app that we create should get its "key" stored withing this keystore?

Answer (score 0):

Remember the key and password for one app and store keystore in one place. Everytime for any  app while it asks you for signing keys ... give the location for the keystore where you have stored your keystore. You don't have to create it everytime.

Comment: I know that. I was talking about should I create a keystore for each app.

Comment: not necessarily for each app ... It depends on you whether you want to sign the app with same signatures or different signatures